# Unable to show menu items in Android toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using a toolbar in place of an action bar in my app. In the toolbar I want to show menu items but I'm unable to add them. Below is my code:

**menu.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:title="Log out"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```xml
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1e70ff</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     if(toolbar != null){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"NOt null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

   }

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    return true
   }

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    if(item.itemId == R.id.logout){
           Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.app.papers">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: can you add some image to the item and try ???

Comment: you mean icon to menu item

Comment: Yes i meant that.

Comment: I tried just now but didn't work still nothing is showing in toolbar.

Comment: accessing toolbar variable correctly then only setting to the support action bar?

Comment: what I did wrong please let me now.

Comment: are you sure you have initialized the toolbar. because if you add `setSupportActionBar(null)` nothing happens

Comment: Yeah its initialized beacause in kotlin I am using synthetic binding in which I dont have to use findViewById() to reference views.

Comment: if you don't see the title in the toolBar so you have an initialization problem in your toolbar

Comment: add icon into resource menu

Comment: @axar I have tried icon but did not work.

Comment: please check if the toolbar isn't null ?

Comment: I have updated code in `MainActivity.java`. NBow I am first checking whether toolbar is null or not but its showing Not null toast which means toolbar is initialized properly.

Answer (score 0):

first do

```
toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.your_tool_bar)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Also call super method :

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

these code work for me

These are my menu file

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_notification"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="Notification"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:iconTint="@color/white"/>
```

set on create method

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Also add these method means override

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.notification_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_notification:
                Toasty.showMessage(getActivity(), "hello test");
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` this for fragments not for activities

Comment: your oncreate option menu code is wrong ...see two times of above code after that if not done then ask it